# issues with Arrays in C#

Tags: c#, arrays

```
Console.WriteLine("Please enter your number of the Names : ?");
int x = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
string[] names = new string[x];
for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
{
    Console.Write("Enter Name no.{0} :  ", i + 1);
    names[i] = Console.ReadLine();
}

Console.WriteLine("the items are {0}", names);
Console.ReadKey();
```

Now when I want to type down the names, it just prints the first Name entered!

Like if I have 5 names, in the last line in the

```
Console.WriteLine("the items are {0}", names);
```

it just prints out the 1st name!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to do a loop at the end as well

Either a `for` loop or a `foreach`, the current way you are using `Console.WriteLine()` is using the `string.Format()` overload

```
foreach (string name in names)
{
    // Write out here
    Console.WriteLine(name);
}
```

Comment: thanks mate! the problem is am not allowed to use 
string.Format() overload
Thanks

Comment: You are using it, its just not doing what you are expecting. Its useful for things like: `sting.format("I like to {0} during the {1}", "Walk", "Day");`

Comment: SIMPLY AWESOME! I TIRED 72 times FINALLY this helped me to put the code together... Programming is like free-writing, nobody should be bound to rules! :)

Answer (score 2):

Join the strings together with the separator you want, before passing them to writeline.

Use string.Join to do so.

Passing an array to WriteLine makes out think you are passing an array with values to format.

Comment: thanks mate, I dont need to just print it out, I mean pass it to the write line, but to another loop as well, which I replace its content with another string!

Answer (score 1):

You have to do a loop.

```
Console.Write("the items are");
for (int i = 0; i < names.Length; ++i)
{
    Console.Write(" ");
    Console.Write(names[i]);
}
Console.WriteLine();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//Console.WriteLine("the items are {0}.", String.Join(", ", names));
string argsFormat = ( 1 < x) ?
    String.Join(", ", Enumerable.Range(0, x).Select(n => "{" + n + "}").ToArray())
    .Replace(", {" + (x-1) + "}", " and {" + (x-1) + "}") + "." 
    :
    argsFormat = "{0}.";
Console.WriteLine("the items are " + argsFormat , names);
```

Comment: Sorry, that's just messy and ugly.